# unnecessary files in grails templates

Tags: grails

I created some templates for the auto-generation code by `grails install-templates`, but some unnecessary files like `form.gsp` are still created. How can I remove them? I cannot find a config file to modify and create only my templates. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grails builds up the list of templates that it needs to generate from by combining the default set of templates in GRAILS_HOME with the ones installed in your app, with the one in your app taking precedence in the case of a name clash.  So if you delete a template from your app's `src/templates` then Grails will simply use the built-in version of that template instead.  I presume this is deliberate don't-repeat-yourself behaviour, to allow you to selectively override some of the templates but stick with the defaults for others without having to have a duplicate copy of the ones you haven't modified.

So I don't think you can prevent the `form.gsp` from being created when you `generate-views`, but if your modified scaffolding templates don't reference it then it does no harm being there and you can just ignore it.  You could create an empty version in your `src/templates`

```
<%-- This file intentionally left blank --%>
```

Answer (score 2):

`grails install-templates` installs a copy of the Grails templates to `src/templates` for you to modify. If you don't care about `form.gsp`, then just ignore it. The templates aren't packaged into your WAR, they are simply used by the Grails `generate-*` commands. If you feel it's necessary to remove it, just don't run `grails install-templates` again. The command only needs to be done once.

Comment: yeah, I  ran install-templates once time, the command that I ran again is "generate-all", and the deleted files turn to be created again. The only problem is the unecessary files in path. Sorry the english

Answer (score 0):

When you execute the command "grails install-templates" it generates a folder src/templates/scaffolding. Inside this folder are the files that will be generated automatically when you execute o comando generete-all/view/controller.

Comment: Yeah, but when I remove the "form.gsp" and run the generation command again, the file turn to be created again.